# Osmnx.plot_graph_folium() not working; folium is not recognized

Tags: python, openstreetmap, folium, osmnx

I'm trying to display a osmnx map like:

```
graph_map = ox.plot_graph_folium(coordinates, popup_attribute ="name", edge_width=2)
```

but I get an error:

```
Cell In[40], line 1
----> 1 graph_map = ox.plot_graph_folium(G, popup_attribute='name', edge_width=2)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/osmnx/folium.py:53, in plot_graph_folium(G, graph_map, popup_attribute, tiles, zoom, fit_bounds, **kwargs)
     51 # create gdf of all graph edges
     52 gdf_edges = utils_graph.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False)
---> 53 return _plot_folium(gdf_edges, graph_map, popup_attribute, tiles, zoom, fit_bounds, **kwargs)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/osmnx/folium.py:127, in _plot_folium(gdf, m, popup_attribute, tiles, zoom, fit_bounds, **kwargs)
    125 # check if we were able to import folium successfully
    126 if folium is None:  # pragma: no cover
--> 127     raise ImportError("folium must be installed to use this optional feature")
    129 # get centroid
    130 x, y = gdf.unary_union.centroid.xy

ImportError: folium must be installed to use this optional feature
```

I am clueless since I imported osmnx and folium successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem's solution is a simple reinstall of osmnx. It should be installed AFTER Scipy nor scikit-learn via pip.